# Laravel validation depending on another model whose ID is on the same form

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I have a form returning fields `entity_id` and `price`.

```
$validated = $request->validate([
            'entity_id' => ['required', 'integer'],
            'price' => ['required', 'numeric', 'min:1'],
        ]);
```

The `price` field should have a `max` rule, but that value comes from the chosen `Entity` that has a `max_price` field. That value should then be set as `max`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [Custom validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules).

One of the custom validation is to use closure

```
$validated = $request->validate([
            'entity_id' => ['required', 'integer'],
            'price' => [
                'required', 
                'numeric', 
                'min:1', 
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                    $max = Entity::where('id',$request->entity_id)->value('max_price');
                    //$max will be the desired value OR NULL
                    if (isset($max) && $max < $value) {
                        $fail('The '.$attribute.' is higher than the allowed max '.$max.'.');
                    }
                }
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: Yeah I guess so... Though `$this->entity_id` won't work, I will need to create a Rule class with `DataAwareRule`. Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyBelolo yeah, replace `$this->entity_id` by `$request->entity_id`. I was thinking about FormRequest class